# Packaging a Pytest Test File as an executable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pytest

So I've designed a Pytest testing package which consists of a python script:

```
class TestClass():

   test_a()

   test_b()
```

I'm wondering if I can package my tests as an executable and run it?
The reason for this being that I want to avoid installing python and python packages on all the machines where I’m going to execute the tests.

Answer (score 2):

Create a python file and invoke tests from there using pytest package:

```
import pytest

pytest.main(['mytestdir'])
```

package main.py and test files in an executable as you would do with any python project. Keep main.py as your executable entry point.

More info about running pytest from python: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code

Comment: i'm familiar with the pytest.main implementation:

`code pytest.main(['-v', '--durations=0', '--junitxml', junit_path,  '--tb', 'long'])`

Comment: See my reply to the commend above

Comment: You can use `pytest.main(["-s", __file__])` in the test file to be able to simply run it with `python test_file.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what you want to accomplish, here is where I got. I used a modified version of your code that can run on it's own.

```
import pytest

class TestSanity(): 
    def test_step_1(self): 
        assert 2==2 
#        if __name__ == "__main__": 
        test=pytest.main(['-v', '-x', '--durations=0'])
        print(test)


TestSanity().test_step_1()
```

I saved this as "pytest_with_pyinstaller.py"

Then I used this line in the anaconda prompt to package the pyinstaller file

```
pyinstaller --exclude-module PyQt5 --hidden-import pytest.mark --hidden-import py._builtin    --onefile --hidden-import pytest.main U:\PLAN\BCUBRICH\Python\Tests\pytest_with_pyinstaller.py
```

Then I ran the resulting .exe from a windows cmd console.

```
>Run>cmd
>cd "your output director"
>"your_exe.exe"
```

C:\Users\bcubrich\dist\test2>pytest_with_pyinstaller.exe
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.0.2, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0 -- C:\Users\bcubrich\dist\test2\pytest_with_pyinstaller.exe
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: C:\Users\bcubrich\dist\test2, inifile:
collected 0 items

======================== no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================

5

The 5 at the end of this seems to be the pytest line, and is the same number I get when I run this code in spyder, so I think it's working, except that the pytest script will try to test anything in the dist directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will try a small scale experiment with your suggested solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyinstaller if your script is written in a way that lends itself to running as an exe. If you use anaconda then you just need to run

```
pyinstaller --onefile path_to_your_file
```

though i commonly run something like this to avoid errors I get with PyQt5

```
pyinstaller --onefile --exclude-module PyQt5 --noconsole C:\username\etc\script.py
```

https://www.pyinstaller.org/

look at the following for freezing your script with pytest

"Freezing pytest

If you freeze your application using a tool like PyInstaller in order to distribute it to your end-users, it is a good idea to also package your test runner and run your tests using the frozen application. This way packaging errors such as dependencies not being included into the executable can be detected early while also allowing you to send test files to users so they can run them in their machines, which can be useful to obtain more information about a hard to reproduce bug.

Fortunately recent PyInstaller releases already have a custom hook for pytest, but if you are using another tool to freeze executables such as cx_freeze or py2exe, you can use pytest.freeze_includes() to obtain the full list of internal pytest modules. How to configure the tools to find the internal modules varies from tool to tool, however.

Instead of freezing the pytest runner as a separate executable, you can make your frozen program work as the pytest runner by some clever argument handling during program startup. This allows you to have a single executable, which is usually more convenient. Please note that the mechanism for plugin discovery used by pytest (setupttools entry points) doesn’t work with frozen executables so pytest can’t find any third party plugins automatically. To include third party plugins like pytest-timeout they must be imported explicitly and passed on to pytest.main."

```
# contents of app_main.py
import sys
import pytest_timeout  # Third party plugin

if len(sys.argv) > 1 and sys.argv[1] == "--pytest":
    import pytest

    sys.exit(pytest.main(sys.argv[2:], plugins=[pytest_timeout]))
else:
    # normal application execution: at this point argv can be parsed
    # by your argument-parsing library of choice as usual
    ...
```

This large block quote comes from [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html).

Comment: That's the whole problem if you write the PyTest script to be run as an EXE. Then you loose the whole structure of the pytest architecture and it's just another py/exe script which does not produce neither the console output report nor the Junit XML report which allows Jenkins and the likes of it to produce a report

Comment: pyinstaller should write to the console if you don't use the "--no-console" parameter, but I don't know about pytest writing to the console.

Comment: Hey @bart cubrich , so i've tried to implement your suggested solution , i used the 
`code pyinstaller pythonscript.py` command to generate the executable (it came with the dist folder as described in the Pyinstaller documentation). The problem is that it's not picking any of the tests in the script. The script is built in the following matter :
`code class TestSanity:'
     `code test_1`
     `code test_2`
`code if __name__ == "__main__":`
`code pytest.main(['-v', '-x', '--durations=0', '--junitxml', junit_path])`
when excuting i get _italic collected 0 items

Comment: To help you with this more I would need to see some code, and I would also need to see the line you are running in the command prompt to initial pyinstaller.

Comment: Hi, code is below: 



   `code class TestSanity(BaseTest):
                  def test_step_1(self):
                     assert 2==2
           if __name__ == "__main__":
               pytest.main(['-v', '-x', '--durations=0')`



Command i'm using to iniate pyinstaller:  `codepyinstaller mytestscript.py`