# How to run a crontab job on macos Monterey with a pytest(python) file?

Tags: python, macos, cron, pytest

I have a simple pytest test file that calls a Page calls and outputs a CSV file, the test runs fine in the terminal.

```
from generic_framework_code.teststat import TestStatus
import unittest
import pytest
from generic_framework_code.random_scripts.new_script import Newscript
import generic_framework_code.utilities.custom_logger as cl
import logging

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("NewSetup", "setup")
class NewTest(unittest.TestCase):
    log = cl.testLogger(logging.DEBUG)

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def classSetup(self, NewSetup):
        self.ts = TestStatus(self.driver)
        self.ns = Newscript(self.driver)

    @pytest.mark.run(order=1)
    def test_ns_subtest(self):
        self.ns.print_csv()
```

here is page class below

```
from generic_framework_code.base.basepage import BasePage
import generic_framework_code.utilities.custom_logger as cl 
import logging  


class Newscript(BasePage):
    log = cl.customLogger(logging.INFO)

    def __init__(self, driver):
        super().__init__(driver)
        self.driver = driver

    def print_content(self):
        does the job
```

These scripts run fine on my local machine with the usual pytest /user..../test_file.py command.
I want to set a cronjob on my macOS to run every day at 9am, but nothing seems to happen
I went with `crontab -e` and added the following command

```
0 09 * * * /Users/abc/PycharmProjects/fullpath_to_file/tests/test_file.py
```

also tried this https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-easily-automate-your-python-scripts-on-mac-and-windows-459388c9cc94
any help is appreciated.

**Update**
I did some reading on stack and created another python file and invoked the pytest from there

```
import pytest

pytest.main(['/Users/full_path/tests/test_file.py'])
```

when I run this file in the terminal with python3 /Users/full_path/tests/test_file.py it runs fine but inserting in crontab and checking the log says

```
"Exceptions:
         - WebDriverException : Raised either when it can't start the service
           or when it can't connect to the service
```

Comment: It's most likely some difference in environment -- cron jobs have a very minimal environment, so no `PYTHONPATH` etc by default. Log the output & errors by adding something like `>>/tmp/test_file.log 2>&1` to the cron job, then check the log to see what it indicates.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I get a permission denied message on the log file. 
I also created another python file based of some reading here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982745/packaging-a-pytest-test-file-as-an-executable I created another python file with the following code 
import pytest
pytest.main(['/path_to_testfile.py'])
again this run fine in terminal but not in crontab, I get the "Cant service" message for selenium